# no cipher suites in common on Liberty Websphere

Tags: ssl, openssl, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to set up SSL on my Websphere-Liberty server with a self-sigend CA, but I keep getting a SSLHandshakeException. I'm no SSL expert, so probably I'm just forgetting something.

Here are some details about my setup:

```
product = WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0 (wlp-1.0.3.20130510-0831)
java.version = 1.7.0_51
os = Windows 8 (6.2; amd64) (en_US)
```

I managed to deploy the worklight application center war, and this is accessible via the browser. When I try to access the application center via https, I get the following exception:

```
[9/1/14 19:07:11:799 EEST] 00000021 com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLHandshakeErrorTracker     E CWWKO0801E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired. Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

I have the following configuration in my server.xml

```
<feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="trasys" />
```

Once I add the keystore property, Websphere generates a keystore file (key.jks) with a default certificate. I removed the certificate with the java keytool utility and added my own self-signed CA certificate. This certificate was generated in cygwin using the following openssl command (as indicated in the following stackoverflow ticket: [Is a signed SSL certificate required for Worklight development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773046/is-a-signed-ssl-certificate-required-for-worklight-development/19841469#19841469)):

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt
```

To add the certificate to the empty keystore I used the following command:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mydomain -file certificate.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

So this is basically what I tried so far, does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only import public certificate, not the private key using your procedure. You need private key in your keystore.
You can use the following solutions:

- convert your key and certificate to the pkcs12 and then import as described here [importing an existing x509 certificate and private key in Java keystore to use in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224863/3701228)
- create certificate using Liberty tool `securityUtility createSSLCertificate` as described [securityUtility command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_command_securityutil.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-11-0-4-1-2-0&lang=en)
- if you have full WebSphere Application Server you can use IBM Key Management utility (ikeyman) to create and import keys and certificates.

Comment: Thx, this indeed solved my problem. To be complete; I converted my certificate and key with the following openssl command: openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.crt -inkey privateKey.key -out certificate.p12 -name hiper-certificate. Then I added this p12 file to the keystore via portecle.